# Why does this extremely simple PHP code not work? syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, html

I have just signed up for Treehouse training and I have this mini challenge to complete. 
I can't get this to work. If the variable is set to 'vanilla' I will get a successful output. However, if I use 'cookie dough' then I get a syntax error, I think it may be because of the space between cookie and dough in the varial prehaps?

```
 <?php 
        $flavor = cookie dough;
        echo "<p> Your favourite flavor is ";
        echo $flavor;
        echo ".</P>";
        if ($flavor == "cookie dough") {
            echo "<p> Yeah I like cookie dough aswell! </p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you want tp check in php.net how to assign strings to variable. You need to quote them.

Comment: You need to learn how to [READ and debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the error message. on the line given in the error message you have a string that php did not expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you forgot `""`

```
$flavor = cookie dough;
```

should be

```
$flavor = "cookie dough";
          ^            ^
```

Comment: +1 , Neat representation !

Comment: Brilliant! Simple mistake, wont happen again! :)

Comment: @yogesh Suthar
Why does it work when I use `flavour = vanilla` and then set the conditional to check if the variable is equal to `vanilla`. Does it only have to be in quotation marks when using multiple words?

Comment: @AshleyBrown, Exactly. You need to wrap them in quotes to treat them as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose `$flavor` variable value with quotes.

```
<?php 
        $flavor = "cookie dough";
        echo "<p> Your favourite flavor is ";
        echo $flavor;
        echo ".</P>";
        if ($flavor == "cookie dough") {
            echo "<p> Yeah I like cookie dough aswell! </p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
$flavor = cookie dough;
```

isn't a correct code, enclose with quotes. You can see possible ways to define strings [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$flavor = cookie dough;
```

should be

`$flavor = 'cookie dough';` or

```
$flavor = "cookie dough";
```

To define a string you should be use `"'"` or `'"'`;

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose `cookie dough` in quotes:

```
$flavor = "cookie dough";
```